# Symfony2 Form Error - Why?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I have a form that I have built in symfony2.

```
$builder->add('purchaseOrder','text');
$builder->add('product', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'WICProductBundle:Product',
        'property' => 'name',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->where('p.account=?1')
                ->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC')
                ->setParameter(1,$this->account);
        }
   ));
```

When I output this form in Twig and submit it, it works fine!

When I change my form builder to this and submit the form, I get an error?!?!

```
$builder->add('purchaseOrder','text');
$builder->add('product','text');
```

The first iteration of the form I fill in the purchase order field with 8 and I select an option in the product drop down with the value of 65... All works well...

The second iteration of the form I fill in the purchase order field with 8 and I fill in the product field with the value of 65... And I get this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to WIC\PurchaseOrderLineItemBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrderLineItem::setProduct() must be an instance of WIC\ProductBundle\Entity\Product, string given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfonydev/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Util/PropertyPath.php on line 538 and defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfonydev/src/WIC/PurchaseOrderLineItemBundle/Entity/PurchaseOrderLineItem.php line 302
```

Why would my form break from a swapping out a drop down to a text box if the same value of "65" is being passed each time?

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yeah, its not the cache. I think it has to do with the fact that initally "query_builder" was creating an object for the product, then when I changed it to a simple text field the object no longer existed. I just dont know how to create an object out of a text field or it is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find formal explanation regarded to this subject in [symfony official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/index.html), but AFAIK any form field which represents a relation should be rendered by [`Entity Field Type`](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html). that's the only way symfony's basic form functionality works to render and persist a form's field that represents an entity.

Nevertheless you can use [`Data Transformers`](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) to achieve exactly what you wish.

from symfony [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html):

> Say you have a one-to-one relation of Task to Issue, e.g. a Task optionally has an issue linked to it. Adding a listbox with all possible issues can eventually lead to a really long listbox in which it is impossible to find something. You might want to add a textbox instead, where the user can simply enter the issue number.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an entity through a text field, you should add a custom model data transformer to your field which converts your "text" representation of the entity to the "real" entity & reverse transform an entity to his "text" representation.

That will avoid your model to end up with a PHP fatal error due to the setter typehint.